# Fill scipy sparse.coo_matrix by for loop

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to iteratively fill a scipy sparse coo_matrix

```
# Constructing an empty matrix
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
m = coo_matrix((3, 4), dtype=np.int8)
```

by a for loop and some rules, e.g. all ones (I know there's a constructor with data but I can't use it since the rule is more complex). How can I do that? I haven't found any documentation about it.

Comment: What's wrong with preparing data and co. in the loop (a-priori; then build coo)? What's to complex? What will this loop be producing? The only direct-access to elements is probably dok_matrix; but that will be slow in most cases.

Comment: `coo` doesn't even provide a way of indexing elements, much less setting zeros to new non-zero values.  `dok` and `lil` are the best formats for iterative assignment.  Usually we create the `row`, `col`, `data` arrays first, and then make the `coo` matrix from those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **not** directly fill a scipy sparse.coo_matrix by for loop

Your best option is to convert the coo_matrix to a [dok_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html) that can be indexed like a dictionary, and later revert it back to coo_matrix if needed.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
m = coo_matrix((3, 4), dtype=np.int8)

m = m.todok() # convert to dok
for i in xrange(10):
    for j in xrange(5):
        m[i, j] = i + j # update the matrix, note the particular access format

m = m.tocoo() # convert back to coo
```

This is the fastest way, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30195150/7067655).